# latest free and easy to use web barcode scanner?

Tags: web-applications, barcode-scanner

Which is the latest free and easy to use web barcode scanner ?

I am building a .net/asp web application and need to implement a functionality to scan barcodes using a tablet or smartphone.
I have found [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) but its a bit difficult to use and is draining my battery very fast while using.

Comment: Can check out [WebAssembly Zxing](https://github.com/yushulx/zxing-cpp-emscripten) >

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 client targets, perhaps consider using native APIs like Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeSanner.

GitHub samples can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

Comprehensive API documentation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-camerabarcode

For a ready to go store app see http://aka.ms/JustScanIt